# Database.Stateful does not work as expected when using instance variable of another class

Tags: apex, batch, stateful

We have private field `service` which is instance of `HelperService`. `HelperService` is pretty heavy class, that performs several callouts, transforms responses into Salesforce objects and logs errors which will be used for email messaging in the batch's `finish` method.

Based on query generation logic in the `start` method, batch either enters `execute` method and fails because of NullPoiner, or do not receive records for processing and proceeds to `finish` method where it fails with the same NullPoiner exception. `service` field appears to be null, even though we have instantiated it.

As seen on piece of code below `service` field is not static, and `Database.Stateful` interface has been implemented which means instance of `HelperService` should be serialized between chunks. This issue is not reproducible on sandbox, occur only in production. Also it fails only when ran via scheduler, manual launch with anonymous apex worked as expected, issue did not occur.

Have someone faced such behavior, if so - is there any possible workarounds? Thanks everyone in advance.

```
public class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private final HelperService service = new HelperService();


    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        //Start logic...
    }


    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> records) {

        service.setBar(...) //Here NullPointer exception occurrs
    }


    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        service.getFoo() //Here NullPointer exception occurrs
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove 'final' from service variable declaration?

Comment: @wesaw
final worked fine for all previous jobs. We`ll remove final with next deploy, but for now we are stuck with what we have.

Answer (score 3):

In [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) we have an example with `private final String initialState;` variable. This batch class does not implement `Database.Stateful`. Maybe you should just remove `final` keyword because we implement this interface and mark this variable as `public`?

Also, investigate this [article](http://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2019/batch-apex-variables.php). It could be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks Pavlo. I've seen this article, it did not help that much. We'll remove `final` during next deployment.

Answer (score 2):

There might be specific known issue in specific version of Salesforce API if issue occurs on Production but isn't seen in Sandbox.

For example, if your production has winter 19 release and sandbox has spring 20 release, the issue may exist in Winter 19 and may be fixed in spring 20.

First of all, open Salesforce support case to find out root cause and perform Root Cause Analysis. Provide information to Salesforce support about versions where issue is reproduced and where is not.

Also, please look through possible related knows issues (which may or may not be related to your actual case):
[Stateful batch job that stores Database.SaveResult (failed after validation errors) throws error during deserialization](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SWQXAA4)

[Inconsistency of behaviour in BaseBatchApexRangeChunkHandler vs. BatchApexJobItemHandler, when implementing Database.Stateful](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y1OAAU)

As a workaround, try

1. remove `final` keyword
2. move initialiser into batch constructor.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We'll remove `final` keyword, as well as adding additional HelperService instance fields, with different initializing methods.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with the following code:

```
public class StatefulBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful
{
    private final StatefulBatchHelper helper = new StatefulBatchHelper();

    public List<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext c)
    {
        System.debug(helper.a);
        System.debug(helper.b);
        return new List<SObject>{new Contact()};
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext c, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        System.debug(helper.a);
        System.debug(helper.b);    
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext c)
    {
        System.debug(helper.a);
        System.debug(helper.b);
    }
}

public class StatefulBatchHelper 
{
    public integer a = 5;
    public final string b = 'test';
}
```

After running it with both classes in API version 47, 46, and 43, I haven't been able to replicate the issue in the OP, the correct values are printed.  I also tried doing a JSON serialization round trip and didn't have any issue.  If removing `final` doesn't solve the issue, it might be worth trying to remove pieces from `HelperService` and testing to see if there is some member variable causing a serialization issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a month of communication with Salesforce support we received following message:

> Database.stateful is used to maintain the common handle and check the
>   process but the Bean life cycle will not be maintained as per my
>   analysis. Instead of instantiating the bean at class level. we
>   recommend to instantiate the object in method level(i.e., execute,
>   final start methods) and pass by reference wherever required in order
>   to ensure the scope of the bean created.

Therefore using one service instance for whole batch class is not recommended.